# Wie nennt man diese Art Nebensatz?

Tags: grammar-identification

"Und nun zum Wetter für den in Deutschland am häufigsten vorkommenden Baum, der Fichte."

Dieser Satz kam so in einer Talkshow vor und in den Kommentaren gab es Diskussionen zum Nebensatz "der Fichte".
https://youtu.be/y5BPwPUQOd8

Insbesondere wurde angedeutet, es sollte "die Fichte" heißen. Ich bin mir zwar ziemlich sicher, dass "der Fichte" korrekt ist, weiß aber nicht, wie dies zu begründen ist. Deshalb würde ich gerne fragen, wie man diesen Satz/Nebensatz nennt, falls es denn einer ist, und nach welchen Regeln der Fall des Artikels bestimmt wird.

Comment: Der Satz ergibt überhaupt keinen Sinn. *Für* verlangt Akkusativ. Es muss also *die Fichte* heißen.

Comment: Der Moderator hat im Kopf einen falschen Bezug hergestellt: *zum Wetter, ... [zu] der Fichte* statt *für den häufigsten Baum, [für] die Fichte*.

Comment: Der Satz ergibt auch mit dem richtigem Fall keinen Sinn. Das ist nicht unbedingt überraschend in einer von Herrn Winterscheidt moderierten Sendung. Aber was soll das denn heißen, *zum Wetter für die Fichte* ?

Comment: @Olafant, ob es ums Wetter für Berliner, für Allergiker oder für Fichten geht, die Sinnhaftigkeit des Satzinhalts ist für das Problem der Kasuskongruenz nicht relevant. Außerdem kennen wir den Kontext nicht. Wenn es zum Beispiel vorher ums klimabedingte Baumsterben ging, dann ist eine solche Überleitung durchaus nicht ungewöhnlich. PS: Ich habe das Video nicht gesehen!

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Der erste Satz stimmt. Der zweite ist sehr gewagt, wenn man das Video nicht einmal gesehen hat. Was die (mögliche) Verbindung zu vorherigem Nonsense (mehr kann es bei dieser Art von Fernsehunterhaltung wirklich nicht sein) angeht: das mag sein. Da bin ich vielleicht zu lange zu weit weg von der deutschen Verblödungslampe (Fernsehen). ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es handelt sich hier um einen [Beisatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition), der das Bezugswort näher beschreibt und es ersetzen könnte. Deshalb hat der Beisatz auch, [bis auf ein paar Ausnahmen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition#Inkongruenter_Kasus), denselben Kasus wie das Bezugswort. Hier steht *Baum* im Akkusativ (*für den […] Baum*), daher muss auch *Fichte* im Akkusativ stehen, was man leicht einsieht, wenn man die Ersetzungsprobe macht:

> - Und nun zum Wetter *für der* […] *Fichte*.   (Genitiv oder Dativ, falsch)
> - Und nun zum Wetter *für die* […] *Fichte*.   (Akkusativ, richtig)

Der Satz sollte demnach lauten:

> Und nun zum Wetter *für den* in Deutschland am häufigsten vorkommenden *Baum*, *die Fichte*.

Comment: Super, danke! Laut Wikipedia wäre das anscheinend ein inkongruenter Dativ: "Der inkongruente Dativ hingegen gilt standardsprachlich nicht als korrekt:

Die Fotografien des jungen Mannes, einem Künstler aus Indien, stießen auf großes Interesse." Der Fehler ist anscheinend verbreitet, wenn es dafür einen Wikipedia Eintrag gibt.